# Swagger Custom Model

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Im using swagger and spring boot to automatically generate API docs for my objects.  However I'm dynamically adding fields to my json reponse using @jsonAnyGetter @jsonAnySetter.   Such as

```
public class SomeResponse {

    //Standard part picked up by swagger
    public String field1;
    public String field2;

    //Dynamic Part not picked up by Swagger
    private HashMap dynamicFields = new HashMap();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public final void putDynamicField(String key, Object value){
        dynamicFields.put(key, value);
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public final HashMap getDynamicFields(){
        return dynamicFields;
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
{
   "field1":""
   "field2":""
}
```

NB  when the dynamic fields appear the magic of jackson make them appear at the same level at field1/2  :)  HOwever Swagger doesnt pick them up cause they appear at run-time obvioulsy

Can anyone tell me how I can update the generated Swagger Model or Model Schema description to add custom fields description of sorts of my own naming?  Something like:

```
{
   "field1":""
   "field2":""

   "dynamicField1": {}
   "dynamicFieldN": {}

}
```

Comment: *Such as....* - such what?

Comment: Sorry @Andremoniy. I posted prematurely.  I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

The `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter` are not supported by Swagger.  You'll have to have concrete model definitions, or configure a custom model converter to add run-time fields to your models.

Comment: Thanks @fehguy.  Can you point me to where I can see how to set concrete model definitions please?  Also I can't find documentation on how to write/config CustomModelConverters.  Any pointers?

Comment: A concrete model definition would be an ordinary pojo or model interface.  For a CustomModelConverter, please take a look here for the interface: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-core/src/main/java/io/swagger/converter/ModelConverter.java and to these tests for implementation samples: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-core/src/test/java/io/swagger/model/override/SamplePropertyConverter.java